# How can I get ads preview link using Facebook ads sdk in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, facebook-ads-api

Мy code for preview:

```
creative = AdCreative(6064648xxxxxx)
ad_preview = creative.get_previews(
    params={'ad_format': AdPreview.AdFormat.desktop_feed_standard}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get ad preview at creative level you have to print your ad preview.

```
    creative = AdCreative('60xxxxxxxx')
    params = {
        'ad_format': AdPreview.AdFormat.desktop_feed_standard,
    }
    ad_preview = creative.get_previews(params=params)

    for p in ad_preview:
        preview = p["body"]
        preview = str(preview)

    preview = preview.replace("amp;", "")
    preview = (preview.split('src="')[1].split('" width')[0])
print preview
```

use this code change creative id.